# I want to pass a text string from a file to a dialog --menu in bash

Tags: bash, shell, dialog

I'm trying to get this text string:

```
0 "Item: Bitterweed, Amount: 4" 1 "Item: Agarita, Amount: x" 2 "Item: Wild Rhubarb, Amount: x" 3 "Item: Cardinnal Flower, Amount: x" 4 "Item: Creek Plum, Amount: x" 5 "Item: Blood Flower, Amount: " 6 "Item: Chocolate Daisy, Amount: x" 7 "Item: Wisteria, Amount: x"
```

To be passed to the dialog application in bash.

I'm trying to create a menu from this.

The string gets updated by a function.

The string is placed in a variable $mitem.

I then run

```
dialog --menu "Choose item to modify" 15 55 5 $mitem
```

This however keeps telling me "**Error: Expected 2 arguments, found extra 1.**"

When i copy paste the string from the variable and run dialog without the $mitem variable it does work.

```
dialog --menu "Choose item to modify" 15 55 5 0 "Item: Bitterweed, Amount: 4" 1 "Item: Agarita, Amount: x" 2 "Item: Wild Rhubarb, Amount: x" 3 "Item: Cardinnal Flower, Amount: x" 4 "Item: Creek Plum, Amount: x" 5 "Item: Blood Flower, Amount: " 6 "Item: Chocolate Daisy, Amount: x" 7 "Item: Wisteria, Amount: x"
```

Could anyone explain to me why this will not work from my variable but does when I manually add the string, and when for instance this works fine:

```
var=$(df -hT | awk '{print v++,$7}')
dialog --menu "Please choose a mounted Partition" 15 55 5 $var
```

I thank you.

A more complete picture:

```
echo "\"Item: $item, Amount: $amount\"" >> ~/tmp2

cat ~/tmp2
"Item: Bitterweed, Amount: 4"
"Item: Agarita, Amount: x"
"Item: Wild Rhubarb, Amount: x"
"Item: Cardinnal Flower, Amount: x"
"Item: Creek Plum, Amount: x"
"Item: Blood Flower, Amount: "
"Item: Chocolate Daisy, Amount: x"
"Item: Wisteria, Amount: x"

mitem=$(gawk '{print v++,$0}' ~/tmp2)     

echo $mitem
0 "Item: Bitterweed, Amount: 4" 1 "Item: Agarita, Amount: x" 2 "Item: Wild Rhubarb, Amount: x" 3 "Item: Cardinnal Flower, Amount: x" 4 "Item: Creek Plum, Amount: x" 5 "Item: Blood Flower, Amount: " 6 "Item: Chocolate Daisy, Amount: x" 7 "Item: Wisteria, Amount: x"

dialog --menu "Choose item to modify" 15 55 5 $mitem
```

Comment: Add quotes to `"$mitem"` to prevent word splitting.

Comment: I have thought of that, however when doing this dialog sees it as one argument while the menu gets build from 2 arguments, the tag (number) and the content (string between " "), this can be repeated several times.
It's strange though since it does work when i copy paste the exact same string as I'm trying to pass to dialog with the variable. Also the string I copy paste is a direct copy from and echo of $mitem.
It baffles me.

Comment: Then pas an array of two arguments: The item name string and the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Since some of the arguments being passed to `dialog` contain spaces (for instance `"Item: Bitterweed, Amount: 4"`), I would prepare the arguments as array,

```
mitem=(0 "Item: Bitterweed, Amount: 4" ....)
```

and interpolate it using

```
dialog --menu "Choose item to modify" 15 55 5 "${mitem[@]}"
```

to ensure that no word splitting occurs inside the array elements.

Comment: Good suggestion. I feel like something is awry with my csv or something. I keep getting strange results. Thanks for the help though!